# Spotify login error -canOpenURL

Tags: ios, spotify

I'm trying to understand Spotify's login/authorization process. I was following a tutorial and ended up with this code. When I try to login I get this error:
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "spotify-action://" - error: "(null)"

I checked the repo and saw that I needed to add spotify-action and spotify to Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. However after doing this I am still getting the above error.

```
class SpotifyLoginViewController: UIViewController, SPTAuthViewDelegate{
let kclientID = " my client id"
let kcallbackURL = "my callback"

@IBAction func loginSpotify(sender: AnyObject){
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().clientID = kclientID
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().redirectURL = NSURL(string: kcallbackURL)
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().requestedScopes = [SPTAuthStreamingScope]
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().sessionUserDefaultsKey = "SpotifySession"
    //SPTAuth.defaultInstance().tokenSwapURL = NSURL(string: ktokenSwapURL) //you will not need this initially, unless you want to refresh tokens
   // SPTAuth.defaultInstance().tokenRefreshURL = NSURL(string: ktokenRefreshServiceURL)//you will not need this unless you want to refresh tokens

    let spotifyAuthViewController = SPTAuthViewController.authenticationViewController()
    spotifyAuthViewController.delegate = self
    spotifyAuthViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
    spotifyAuthViewController.definesPresentationContext = true
    presentViewController(spotifyAuthViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

}


func authenticationViewController(authenticationViewController: SPTAuthViewController!, didLoginWithSession session: SPTSession!) {
    print("Logged In")
}

func authenticationViewController(authenticationViewController: SPTAuthViewController!, didFailToLogin error: NSError!) {
    print("Failed to Log In")
    print(error)
    authenticationViewController.clearCookies(nil)
}

func authenticationViewControllerDidCancelLogin(authenticationViewController: SPTAuthViewController!) {
    print("User Canceled Log In")
    authenticationViewController.clearCookies(nil)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the Spotify app isn't installed on your device. so you can not open the Spotify Original app with the URL "spotify-action://".
You can login with the web browser.
It will open the spotify.com and after authentication, it will redirects to the redirect url (app link ).

You have to change only one parameter.
**sessionManager.initiateSession(with: scope, options: *.clientOnly*, presenting: self)**
That param is options. 
Please change this to ***.default***.
So it will open the safari browser to login the spotify account.
I hope this will be help.

Answer (score 0):

If the Spotify app isn't installed on your device then the action to open Spotify will fail and the console will print the error: -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "spotify-action://" - error: "(null)". This happens for any app that isn't installed on your device and an attempt to launch the non-existing app occurs.